# ¿Es posible Obtener un Dominio del ICAAN sin el servicio de terceros?

Tags: web, dominio

¿Es posible Obtener un Dominio del ICAAN sin el servicio de terceros?

Los Dominios locales con un servidor DNS no me son útiles y no estoy en la disponibilidad de alquilar un dominio a un tercero como: Hostinger, GoDaddy

No he logrado encontrar documentación en español sobre el tema.

**Nota:** Este tema esta relacionado a los Procedimientos de Configuración de un Hosting Publico y forma parte de la configuración/Programación de los DNS y Servicios de Dominios para el acceso a la programación de un sitio web.

Comment: No. Revisa cómo funciona DNS y por qué, así tú configures algo en tu servidor, nadie va a replicarlo y no va a servir más allá de tu red local.

Comment: Sigo pensando que la pregunta esta fuera de tema en el sitio. Abrir este "melon" abre las puertas a muchas preguntas que no tienen nada que ver con la programación. Voy a abrir una pregunta en meta sobre el particular a ver cual es la opinión de la comunidad -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5136/15301

Comment: Si deseas aprender a alojar tu sitio web de forma gratuita y como conectarlo con tu dominio a través de un registrador de dominios y actualizando el DNS con Hostinger. Este tutorial te enseña todo lo que necesitas incluyendo como funciona el internet y varias opciones alternativas:

youtube.com/watch?v=8wOhVltQ7lM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**R1. Actualmente, No es posible, si no eres un registrador.**
Según el sitio del ICAAN, solo lo puede registrar una empresa o Institución que sea acreditada como registradora de Dominios.

Esto es lo que Dice el sitio del ICAAN en español (Traducido):

> Registro de nombres de dominio
>  Los nombres de dominio bajo Nombres de
> dominio de nivel superior genéricos (gTLD) pueden registrarse con uno
> de los más de dos mil registradores acreditados por ICANN o sus
> revendedores. Los registradores están acreditados por la organización
> de la ICANN y certificados por los registros para vender nombres de
> dominio. Están obligados por el Acuerdo de acreditación de
> registradores (RAA) con la organización de la ICANN y por sus acuerdos
> con los registros. Los revendedores son organizaciones afiliadas o
> bajo contrato con registradores para vender nombres de dominio y otros
> servicios ofrecidos por el registrador, como alojamiento web o buzones
> de correo electrónico. Los revendedores están sujetos a sus acuerdos
> con los registradores cuyos servicios venden y no están acreditados
> por la organización de la ICANN. Los registradores siguen siendo
> responsables de todos los nombres de dominio vendidos por sus
> revendedores. La organización de la ICANN mantiene una lista de los
> registradores acreditados por la ICANN en nuestro sitio web.
>
> Los registros de nombres de dominio bajo nombres de dominio de nivel
> superior (ccTLD) de código de país se pueden realizar a través de los
> operadores de ccTLD.
>
> Esta página web agrega contenido existente en el sitio web icann.org
> sobre el tema del registro de un nombre de dominio. Si tiene
> sugerencias o desea enviar una consulta, comuníquese con el Centro de
> soporte global del Centro de soporte global de la organización de la
> ICANN.
>
> Las quejas de cumplimiento contractual se pueden enviar aquí.

Esto es lo que Dice el sitio del ICAAN en Ingles:

> Registering Domain Names Domain names under generic Top-Level Domain
> Names (gTLDs) may be registered with one of more than two thousand
> ICANN-accredited registrars, or their resellers. Registrars are
> accredited by ICANN organization and certified by the registries to
> sell domain names. They are bound by the Registrar Accreditation
> Agreement (RAA) with ICANN organization, and by their agreements with
> the registries. Resellers are organizations affliated with or under
> are under contract with registrars to sell domain names and other
> services offered by the registrar such as web hosting or email
> mailboxes. Resellers are bound by their agreements with the registrars
> whose services they sell and are not accredited by ICANN organization.
> The registrars remain responsible and accountable for all domain names
> sold by their resellers. ICANN organization maintains a list of
> current ICANN-accredited registrars on our website.
>
> Domain name registrations under country-code Top-Level Domain Names
> (ccTLDs) can be made through the ccTLD operators.
>
> This web page aggregates existing content across the icann.org website
> on the topic of registering a domain name. If you have suggestions or
> would like to submit an inquiry, please contact ICANN organization's
> Global Support Center's Global Support Center.
>
> Contractual compliance complaints can be submitted here.

Link del Sitio:
https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/register-domain-name-2017-06-20-en

Link lista de Empresas Registradoras:
https://www.icann.org/en/accredited-registrars

**R2. si es posible, si te conviertes en un registrador.**
Según la estructura y Requisitos del ICAAN puedes pasar de los alquileres si inviertes como lo hizo Google en crear su propia gTLD: como lo explica la Documentación del ICAAN. Pero incluso esta opción tiene sus limitaciones.